# Nginx Reverse Proxy - Not Showing Client's IP

Tags: nginx

I have setup 2 machines. Nginx works as reverse proxy and passes request to Apache Server. Here is my configuration :-

```
   location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_pass http://172.18.0.164:80;
}
```

}

In Apache, i've configured RPAF, here is the configuration for the same :

```
LoadModule rpaf_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_rpaf.so
<IfModule rpaf_module>
RPAF_Enable On
RPAF_SetHostName On
RPAF_ProxyIPs 172.18.8.97
RPAF_Header X-Real-IP
</IfModule>
```

In Apache logs, however it says that request has come from the NGINX IP Address. I was expecting log would rather store the user's IP which has initiated the request instead that of reverse proxy.

I've hosted a simple HTML page.

Is there any things that I should modify ?

Comment: Fix apache to log x-real-ip header

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I was not aware about RPAF. I've added RPAF module. Still i'm getting the NGINX IP instead of the remote address. It seems i've made some mistake in the RPAF configuration.

Comment: I don't know what RPAF is, but my guess that you need http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html

Comment: Thank you so much :D . RPAF was generally used for older versions of Apache. The mod_remoteip seems to be doing the job well :)